# Wikimedia API - Extract JSON or XML from revision wikitext to use in PHP

Tags: php, json, wikimedia

I'm using wikimedia API to extract information abount TV series (year, No. of seasons, genres etc...).

I used a query like this (please see the output):

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions|images&titles=The_Vampire_Diaries&rvprop=timestamp|tags|content&format=json

as you can notice the informations I need are in `revisions` attribute, but it's all plain text.

For instance, what if I want to get series `No. of seasons`, `Genres`, `Country of origin` values from that text?

So what I'd like to ask you is: is there a simple way to access those informations?

I mean maybe there is a way to convert that plain text to JSON or XML in this way it's very easy to access informations.
I know that there is a `parse` wikimedia option to parse revisions text to HTML, but I don't think thata accessing those informations in HTML is the best option for me.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: There isn't an easy way to do this--you will have to do some rudimentary parsing of the wiki page. The data in Wikipedia isn't stored programmatically; it's basically free text, although it is highly organised free text. You'll have to write a parser for the infobox to pull out the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in luck: this is less tricky than it might be because the Wikipedia editors are nice and have given the page some semantic markup.

You have two options. One is to parse the wikitext, as you suggest in your question. The other is to parse the rendered HTML. There are many libraries to parse HTML: parsing wikitext is far harder. So let's parse the HTML instead.

We'll use the [`action=parse`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext#parse) functionality to parse the wikitext for us. We can then specify the title with `page=The_Vampire_Diaries`. Since we're using PHP, we'll use the `format=php` option.

This gives a link like this:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=The_Vampire_Diaries&format=php
```

Excellent. We now have the rendered wikitext. Let's get it into a PHP variable:

```
$url = '...'; // as above
$apiResult = file_get_contents($url);

$parsedResult = unserialize($apiResult);

$renderedHTML = $parsedResult['parse']['text']['*'];
```

We now have the HTML for the page.

Let's use the DOMDocument class to get the elements we want. We're fortunate that the row has a class: `category`. We then want the direct descendent `a` elements.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($renderedHTML);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$elements = $xpath->query('//*[contains(@class, \'category\')]/a');

$genres = array();

foreach($elements as $element) {
    $genres[] = $element->nodeValue;
}
```

So the `$genres` array now contains the values you want. `var_export` gives this:

```
array (
  0 => 'Supernatural drama',
  1 => 'Horror',
  2 => 'Fantasy',
  3 => 'Romance',
)
```

This is, of course, quite vulnerable. If the HTML changed significantly, your code might not work so well. You probably also want to do some error checking, e.g. before calling `unserialize` and `loadHTML`.